# How can I get more data locations detail?

Tags: square

I tried "/v1/me/locations".
But I did not have the data I want.

I want to get more data of locations.(here data -> https://squareup.com/dashboard/locations/)

example :

1. address_line_2+ ( billding name, etc... )
   I could get only "address_line1".
2. Twitter
3. Facebook
4. website url
5. url of brand logo image

Please excuse my poor English.
Am I making sense?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is not currently available from the Square APIs at this time.